# Drop Sql Function with a variable as the function name

Tags: sql-server, function

I want to drop all the functions in a schema, and I don't want to write something that requires me to get all the function names ahead of time and write it in the SQL

```
DROP FUNCTION MySchema.FunctionName1
DROP FUNCTION MySchema.FunctionName2
... etc
```

I tried:

```
DECLARE @FuncName varchar(100)

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) From information_schema.routines 
         WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function') > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT top(1) @FuncName = ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.routines
       WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function'

    BEGIN
        DROP FUNCTION @FuncName  -- it doesn't like it because it is a string variable
    END     

END
```

[sql script to drop old versions of stored procedures and functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7576739/sql-script-to-drop-old-versions-of-stored-procedures-and-functions)
is kinda similar but just generates SQL like the first example and doesn't actually run it

Comment: The technique you are looking for is called [dynamic SQL](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709342(v=vs.85).aspx).  Be extra careful to ensure your [dynamic code is secure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb669091(v=vs.110).aspx).  This technique can open [SQL injection vulnerabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

Comment: Unless a function has been put onto the DB (either by an authorized or unauthorized person), and it was called "MySchema.FunctionName GO DROP TABLE users" or something equally ridiculous I don't see what that comment is trying to tell me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this dynamic sql,

```
DECLARE @FuncName nvarchar(500)

WHILE (SELECT Count(*) From information_schema.routines 
         WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function') > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT top(1) @FuncName = 'DROP FUNCTION ' + SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + '.' + ROUTINE_NAME FROM information_schema.routines
       WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function'

    BEGIN
        EXEC (@FuncName)  -- it doesn't like it because it is a string variable
    END     

END
```

Also you can use below to drop all functions at one go,

```
DECLARE @FuncName nvarchar(MAX) = ''

SELECT @FuncName = @FuncName + 'DROP FUNCTION ' + SPECIFIC_SCHEMA + '.' + ROUTINE_NAME + CHAR(10) 
FROM information_schema.routines
WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function'

EXEC sp_executesql @FuncName
```

Comment: You could also write this without the loop.  Just ensure your drop statements are `GO` delimited and the dynamic query variable is large enough.

Answer (score 0):

Based off Jatin Patel's answer I needed to know the dynamic sql bit! 
(This would have been a comment but stackoverflow couldn't cope with the @ symbols)
I used the following version for readability and the @FuncName keeps it's original meaning

```
DECLARE @FuncName varchar(100)

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) 
       FROM information_schema.routines 
       WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function' ) > 0
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(1) @FuncName = ROUTINE_NAME
    FROM information_schema.routines
    WHERE SPECIFIC_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' AND ROUTINE_TYPE = 'function'

    BEGIN
        EXEC ('DROP FUNCTION MySchema.' + @FuncName)
    END     

END
```